# Static method to swap the values of two objects' property values using Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection, .net-4.5, expression-trees

I'm trying to make a utility function that can Swap two property values given by two lambda expressions - assuming that both expressions indicate properties that have a getter and a setter:

```
Swap(() => John.Lunch, () => Jimmy.Lunch);
```

I imagine the method would need to look something like this, but I'm having trouble pulling it together.

```
private static void Swap<TProperty>(
    Expression<Func<TProperty>> first,
    Expression<Func<TProperty>> second)
{
    PropertyInfo firstProp = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)first.Body).Member;
    PropertyInfo secondProp = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)second.Body).Member;
    object firstObj = (((first.Body as MemberExpression).Expression as MemberExpression)
        .Expression as ConstantExpression).Value;
    object secondObj = (((second.Body as MemberExpression).Expression as MemberExpression)
        .Expression as ConstantExpression).Value;
    TProperty temp = (TProperty)firstProp.GetValue(firstObj);
    firstProp.SetValue(firstObj, secondProp.GetValue(secondObj));
    secondProp.SetValue(secondObj, temp);
}
```

Getting to the "subject" object of the expression is proving to be difficult, although I'm pretty sure it's possible.

Comment: Is this supposed to work on any object type as long as the properties have assignable types or this method is going to swap properties of same type of objects?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü I was thinking it might as well be able to work on any two different objects with any two different properties, as long as both properties are the same type. We could even go further and say try swapping any two values, and just let it blow up if one runtime value isn't assignable to the other property type.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the swap itself with `Expression` trees:

```
private static void Swap<TProperty>(
        Expression<Func<TProperty>> first,
        Expression<Func<TProperty>> second)
{
    var firstMember = first.Body as MemberExpression;
    var secondMember = second.Body as MemberExpression;
    var variable = Expression.Variable(typeof(TProperty));

    var firstMemberAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(firstMember.Expression, firstMember.Member);
    var secondMemberAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(secondMember.Expression, secondMember.Member);

    var block = Expression.Block(new []{ variable },
        Expression.Assign(variable, firstMemberAccess),
        Expression.Assign(firstMemberAccess, secondMemberAccess),
        Expression.Assign(secondMemberAccess, variable)
    );

    Expression.Lambda<Action>(block).Compile()();
}
```

Example:

```
class A { public int P { get; set; } }
class B { public int P2 { get; set; } }

var a = new A { P = 5 };
var b = new B { P2 = 10 };

Swap(() => a.P, () => b.P2);
```

Comment: yep, checked on my environment before i posted

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write code as self explanatory as possible so I will let the comments do the talking. The code needs error checking but I will leave it up to you. Here is the working minimum. I chose a static class for `Swapper` but you can choose to use as instance object then use DI container too.

```
public static class Swapper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Key used for look-ups.
    /// </summary>
    private struct Key
    {
        private readonly Type _tt1;
        private readonly Type _tt2;
        private readonly MemberInfo _m11;
        private readonly MemberInfo _m12;

        public Key(Type t1, Type t2, MemberInfo m1, MemberInfo m2)
        {
            _tt1 = t1;
            _tt2 = t2;
            _m11 = m1;
            _m12 = m2;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            switch (obj)
            {
                case Key key:
                    return _tt1 == key._tt1 && _tt2 == key._tt2 && _m11 == key._m11 && _m12 == key._m12;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var hashCode = (_tt1 != null ? _tt1.GetHashCode() : 0);
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (_tt2 != null ? _tt2.GetHashCode() : 0);
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (_m11 != null ? _m11.GetHashCode() : 0);
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (_m12 != null ? _m12.GetHashCode() : 0);
                return hashCode;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the cache used for compiled actions. Because compiling is time consuming, I think it is better to cache.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Key, object> CompiledActionsCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Key, object>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Main Function which does the swapping
    /// </summary>
    public static void Swap<TSource, TDestination, TPropertySource>(TSource source, TDestination destination, Expression<Func<TSource, TPropertySource>> first, Expression<Func<TDestination, TPropertySource>> second)
    {
        //Try to get value from the cache or if it is cache miss then use Factory method to create Compiled Action
        var swapper = (Action<TSource, TDestination>)CompiledActionsCache.GetOrAdd(GetKey(first, second), k => Factory(first, second));
        //Do the actual swapping.
        swapper(source, destination);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Our factory method which does all the heavy lfiting fo creating swapping actions.
    /// </summary>
    private static Action<TSource, TDestination> Factory<TSource, TDestination, TPropertySource>(Expression<Func<TSource, TPropertySource>> first, Expression<Func<TDestination, TPropertySource>> second)
    {
        //////////////This is our aim/////////////
        //// var temp = obj1.Property;       /////
        //// obj1.Property = obj2.Property;  /////
        //// obj2.Property = temp;           /////
        //////////////////////////////////////////

        // Temp value for required for swapping
        var tempValue = Expression.Variable(typeof(TPropertySource), "temp_value");
        // Expression assignment
        // first.body is already accesing property, just use it as it is :)
        var assignToTemp = Expression.Assign(tempValue, first.Body);
        // Expression assignment
        // second.body is already accesing property, just use it as it is :)
        var secondToFirst = Expression.Assign(first.Body, second.Body);
        // Final switch here
        var tempToSecond = Expression.Assign(second.Body, tempValue);
        // Define an expression block which has all the above assignments as expressions
        var blockExpression = Expression.Block(new[] { tempValue }, assignToTemp, secondToFirst, tempToSecond);
        // An expression itself is not going to swap values unless it is compiled into a delegate
        // (obj1, obj2) => blockExpression from the previous line 
        return Expression.Lambda<Action<TSource, TDestination>>(blockExpression, first.Parameters[0], second.Parameters[0]).Compile();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Key creator method.
    /// </summary>
    private static Key GetKey<TSource, TDestination, TPropertySource>(Expression<Func<TSource, TPropertySource>> first, Expression<Func<TDestination, TPropertySource>> second)
    {
        var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
        var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);
        var sourcePropertyInfo = ((MemberExpression)first.Body).Member;
        var destinationPorpertyInfo = ((MemberExpression)second.Body).Member;
        return new Key(sourceType, destinationType, sourcePropertyInfo, destinationPorpertyInfo);
    }
}
```

Let us see how to use `Swapper` in action

```
public class From
{
    public byte FromProperty { get; set; }
}

public class To
{
    public byte ToProperty { get; set; }
}

var from = new From();
from.FromProperty = 5;
var to = new To();
Swapper.Swap(from, to, f => f.FromProperty, t => t.ToProperty);
```